# Cannot bind Legend layer to Polygon layer in Leaflet/R

Tags: r, leaflet, sf

I try to plot a map of concentrations of chemicals. These have very different ranges, so a shared legend is not feasible. The ultimate goal is to have the different layers for the different chemicals selectable and show the respective legend.

From what I read in the documentation of `addLegend()`, exactly this should be handled by the `group` parameter that was set to the same name in the `addPolygons()` for that layer before. However, it just does not work. Does anyone have an idea for the reason? Here's what I tried:

```
library(spData)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)


set.seed(1)

vietnam <- world %>%
  filter(name_long == "Vietnam")

grids <-
  st_make_grid(vietnam, square = FALSE)

grids_sf <- st_sf(
  id = 1:length(grids),
  geometry = grids,
  category = sample(letters[1:3], size = length(grids), replace = TRUE),
  value = rnorm(length(grids))
)

addPolygonsLayers <- function(map, data, layer_by, fill_by) {

  data_groups <- split(data, data[[layer_by]])
  data_groups_names <- names(data_groups)

  for (i in seq_along(data_groups)) {
    group_data <- data_groups[[i]]
    group_name <- data_groups_names[i]
    group_values <- pull(group_data, fill_by)

    pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "viridis", domain = group_values)

    map <-
      map %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = group_data,
        fillColor = ~ pal(group_values),
        fillOpacity = 1,
        group = group_name,
        popup = str_c(group_name, " </br> Value: ", group_values)
      ) %>%
      addLegend(
        group = group_name,
        opacity = 1,
        pal = pal,
        values = group_values,
        position = "bottomright"
      )
  }
  map <-
    map %>%
    addLayersControl(
      baseGroups = data_groups_names,
      options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE),
      position = "topright"
    )
  return(map)
}


leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygonsLayers(
    data = grids_sf,
    layer_by = "category",
    fill_by = "value"
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom `className` to the legend (it should match the group name), and then, using `htmlwidgets::onRender()`, hide all legends except for the one whose class matches the selected group.

Note that you should keep "info legend" in the `className` since they are important attributes.

Modifying the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59022092/8877639):

```
... %>%
   addPolygonsLayers(
      ...,
      group = "xxx"
   ) %>%
   addLegend(
      ...,
      group = "xxx",
      className = "info legend xxx"
   ) %>%
   addLayersControl(
      baseGroups = c("xxx", ...),
      options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
   ) %>%
   htmlwidgets::onRender("
      function(el, x) {
         var updateLegend = function () {
            var selectedGroup = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')[0].nextSibling.innerText.substr(1);

            document.querySelectorAll('.legend').forEach(a => a.hidden=true);
            document.querySelectorAll('.legend').forEach(l => {
               if (l.classList.contains(selectedGroup)) l.hidden=false;
            });
         };
         updateLegend();
         this.on('baselayerchange', el => updateLegend());
      }"
   )
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is perfect! :)